# show numeric vector with values of length 2 and other values exceeding 10 as na in R

Tags: r

show result with values having digits 2 and na for values having digits more or less than 2

```
v1 <- (123 , 23 , 1234)
```

I want to get the result as `NA , 23 , NA`

Comment: How can you have "values of length 10"?

Comment: Sorry there is a typing mistake . I want to display values which have number of digits equal to 2 and other values i.e. which have more than 2 digits or less than 2 digits to be listed as na .

Comment: How about `replace(v1, v1 %% 100 != v1, NA)`, or `"is.na<-"(v1, v1 %% 100 != v1)`

Answer (score 1):

One simple possibility is to convert to character and check for the number of chars of each number. This assumes you are working with integers. If not, you can simply use `floor()`.

```
v1<- c(123 , 23 , 1234)    
ifelse(nchar(as.character(v1)) > 2, NA, v1)
[1] NA 23 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
NA^((v1 %/% 10) >= 10)*v1
```